# How can I change the ip and port of pm2 web interface?

Tags: node.js, pm2

pm2 web interface - $pm2 web - listen on all the ip available on the machine and I would like it to only listen on localhost or ip of my choice.

```
$pm2 web
Launching web interface on 0.0.0.0:9615
[PM2][WARN] Applications pm2-http-interface not running, starting...
[PM2] App [pm2-http-interface] launched (1 instances)
[PM2] Process launched


pm2 version 2.1.6
node version 4.7.3
```

Thanks

EDITED:

I have researched about the environment variables and for the ip and port are:

```
"env_production" : {
   "NODE_ENV": "production",
   "PM2_API_IPADDR" : "IP here",
   "PM2_API_PORT" : "PORT here"
},
```

I have tried to start the web interface using the ecosystem.json file and I can not get it.

I am going to open another question on this subject.

[How to start pm2 http web interface using the ecosystem.json file?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/42044615/how-to-start-pm2-http-web-interface-using-the-ecosystem-json-file)

Answer (score 2):

To start the pm2 web interface with a different port and/or different listening address you can run it with the environment variable you found set.

eg. `PM2_API_PORT=1234 PM2_API_IPADDR=192.168.1.1 pm2 web`

Answer (score 1):

I recommend setting the environment variables in your `ecosystem.json` file.

So for example, I usually set `NODE_ENV` to be `production` / `development` or `PORT` to be `8080` and maybe, in your case, `HOST` to be `localhost`.

To access them in your node application, use `process.env.<ENVIRONMENT VAR HERE>`.

So for example in your javascript: `var port_num = process.env.NODE_ENV;`

Here's the `pm2` documentation on how to set the environment variables, under the `env` property: http://pm2.keymetrics.io/docs/usage/deployment/

Comment: Thanks for reply kevin, these variables are not for my own script, they are for the http-web-interface included in pm2. In the command line it works with $pm2 web, but using the ecosystem.json file I can not get it. I have edited the question with more info on this subject and I am going to open another new question.