# How to start pm2 http web interface using the ecosystem.json file?

Tags: node.js, pm2

I am trying to start the pm2 web interface using the ecosystem.json file but the following configuration does not work:

```
{
"apps" : [{
"name"        : "web",
"script"      : "",
"args" : ["web"],
"env": {
   "NODE_ENV": "development",
   "PM2_API_IPADDR" : "localhost",
   "PM2_API_PORT" : "1234"
},
"env_production" : {
   "NODE_ENV": "production",
   "PM2_API_IPADDR" : "localhost",
   "PM2_API_PORT" : "1234"
},
"env_staging" : {
   "NODE_ENV" : "staging",
   "PM2_API_IPADDR" : "localhost",
   "PM2_API_PORT" : "1234",
   "TEST"     : true
}
}]
}
```

Comment: report an issue there: https://github.com/Unitech/pm2

Answer (score 2):

Based on https://github.com/Unitech/pm2/blob/master/lib/API/Extra.js#L436, I managed to get this working

Put it as the last item in your ecosystem file, and it will always have the highest id

Make sure that the script path is correct, it was the default on MY system, it might not be on your

I'm running 2.9.3, and the current code (3.5.0) is similar, so it SHOULD work

```
    {
        script : '/usr/local/lib/node_modules/pm2/lib/HttpInterface.js',
        name : 'pm2-http-interface',
        execMode : 'fork_mode',
        env : {
            PM2_WEB_PORT : 9615
        }
    }
```

Answer (score 0):

not sure, but you can try to specify `interpreter`. It should be your PM2 (check it with `whereis`).

Try smth like 

`{
  "apps": [{
    "name": "web",
    "script": "",
    "interpreter": "/usr/local/bin/pm2",
    "args": "web"
  }]
}`

Please note - i didnot checked it at all, it just suggestion